# C# if string contains more than 1 value

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, comparison

Good Morning,

In an `if` statement if we want to check if a string contains a value, we have :

```
if (string.Contains("Value1"))    
{    
}
```

How can we make the string compare with more values in an if statement without keep writing the whole statement? For example to avoid the below statement

```
if ((string.Contains("Value1") && (string.Contains("Value2")) && (string.Contains("Value3")))    
{    
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, basically, you want to check if *all* of your values are contained in the string . Fortunately (with the help of LINQ), this can by translated almost literally into C#:

```
var values = new String[] {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"};

if (values.All(v => myString.Contains(v))) {
    ...
}
```

Similarly, if you want to check if *any* value is contained in the string, you'd substitute `All` by `Any`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could use LINQ:

```
string[] requiredContents = { "Foo", "Bar", "Baz" };

if (requiredContents.All(x => text.Contains(x))
{
    ...
}
```

Note that just like the short-circuiting `&&` operator, [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) will stop as soon as it finds a value which *doesn't* satisfy the condition. (If you want to use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) in a similar way elsewhere, that will stop as soon as it finds a value which *does* satisfy the condition.)

I wouldn't bother for only a reasonably small number though. Without the extraneous brackets, it's really not that bad:

```
if (text.Contains("foo") && text.Contains("bar") && text.Contains("Baz"))
{
}
```

I would only start using the more general form if *either* there were genuinely quite a few values (I'd probably draw the line at about 5) *or* if the set of values was being passed in as a parameter, or varied in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

As you need "your" string to contains all values:

```
var values = new String[] {"Value1", "Value2", "Value3"};
var s = yourString;

if (values.Count(v => s.Contains(v)) == values.Length) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to keep looking after you'd already found one that didn't match?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the best solution? Probably not. Is it readable and extendable? Yes.

```
var matches = {"string1", "string2", "string3","string-n"};
var i = 0;
foreach(string s in matches)
{
    if(mystring.Contains(s))
    {
        i++;
    }
}
if(i == matches.Length)
{
    //string contains all matches.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(stringArray.Any(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s)))
```

If you want to ensure that it contains all the substrings, change `Any` to `All`:

```
if(stringArray.All(s => stringToCheck.Contains(s)))
```